# How to convert output hex to decimal in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to get data from a bluetooth device(heart-rate monitor) where it will show the values of heart rate, pulse rate. when i run the program in terminal the output in comes in hex so any ideas how to display the output in decimal. Thanks..

```
const bluetooth = require('node-bluetooth');

// create bluetooth device instance

const device = new bluetooth.DeviceINQ();

var num = 0;

device
.on('finished',  console.log.bind(console, 'finished'))
.on('found', function found(address, name){
console.log('Found: ' + address + ' with name ' + name);

device.findSerialPortChannel(address, function(channel){
console.log('Found RFCOMM channel for serial port on %s: ', name,     'channel:',channel);

// // make bluetooth connect to remote device
bluetooth.connect(address, channel, function(err, connection){

console.log('North Vision Patient Monitor')

if(err) return console.error(err);

connection.write(new Buffer([0x55,0xAA,0x00], 'utf-8'), () => {

console.log('Send Data')


connection.write(new Buffer([
  0x0b,
  0x40,
  0x85,
  0xB6,
  0xFB,
  0x10,
  0x3C,
  0xC8,
  0xFF,
  0xB4,
  0x28,
  0x28,
  0x0A,
  0x64,
  0x5A,
  0xB4,
  0x3C,
  0x78,
  0x32,
  0xA0,
  0x32,
  0x6E,
  0x46,
  0xB4,
  0x28,
  0x04,
  0x07,
  0x46,
  0x0A,
  0x0A,
  0x00,
  0x00], 'utf-8'), () => {

    console.log('Receive Data')


    });

});


 connection.on('data', (buffer) => {
 console.log('received message:', buffer,'====',num);
 num++;
 });


});

console.log('finished')

});

 // // make bluetooth connect to remote device
// bluetooth.connect(address, channel, function(err, connection){
// if(err) return console.error(err);

// connection.on('data', (buffer) => {
// console.log('received message:', buffer.toString());
// });

// connection.write(new Buffer('Hello!', 'utf-8'));
// });

}).inquire();
```

Output:

North Vision Patient Monitor
Send Data
Receive Data
Buffer 1b a1 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 57 55 51 4c 48 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked in to converting between radices? A simple google search should provide adequate results.

Comment: @jkaufman i have tried some examples from this site (http://xahlee.info/js/js_convert_decimal_hexadecimal.html) but it doesn't work that's why looking for help in stack :(

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you've tried. StackOverflow is not meant to write the code to solve your problem, it is here to help you identify errors in your code that can be solved to rectify your issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
cons bufferInHex = Buffer.from('some string') // init a buffer
console.log(new Uint8Array(bufferInHex)) // display buffer in decimal format
```

Comment: Can you tell, is it correct to convert to Uint8Array and not to Int8Array when reading binary? And why exactly? How do you choose between either one?